# override django - oscar payment

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to save the payment data into admin section of BankCard in Django oscar .

I overrided the paypal code like below  ,but I get an error , saying : 
ValueError at /checkout/preview/

The Bankcard could not be created because the data didn't validate.

Request Method:     POST
The Bankcard could not be created because the data didn't validate.

How can I override the validation?

```
from oscar.apps.checkout.views import PaymentDetailsView as CorePaymentDetailsView
#from .models import PaymentCard as Bankcard
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from oscar.apps.payment.forms import BankcardForm
from oscar.apps.checkout import views
from oscar.apps.payment import forms, models
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse



class PaymentDetailsView(CorePaymentDetailsView):
    template_name = 'paymen_details.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Add data for Paypal Express flow.

        """
        # Override method so the bankcard and billing address forms can be
        # added to the context.
        template_name = 'checkout/payment_details.html'

        ctx = super(PaymentDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['bankcard_form'] = kwargs.get(
            'bankcard_form', forms.BankcardForm())
        """
        ctx['billing_address_form'] = kwargs.get(
            'billing_address_form', forms.BillingAddressForm())
        """
        return ctx

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Override so we can validate the bankcard/billingaddress submission.
        # If it is valid, we render the preview screen with the forms hidden
        # within it.  When the preview is submitted, we pick up the 'action'
        # parameters and actually place the order.
        if request.POST.get('action', '') == 'place_order':
            bankcard_form = forms.BankcardForm(request.POST)
            if bankcard_form.is_valid():
                bankcard_form.save()
            return self.do_place_order(request)

        bankcard_form = forms.BankcardForm(request.POST)
        #billing_address_form = forms.BillingAddressForm(request.POST)
        if not all([bankcard_form.is_valid()]):
                    #billing_address_form.is_valid()]):
            # Form validation failed, render page again with errors
            self.preview = False
            ctx = self.get_context_data(
                bankcard_form=bankcard_form)
             #  " billing_address_form=billing_address_form)
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)

        #bankcard_form.save()

        #billing_address_form = forms.BillingAddressForm(request.POST)


        # Render preview with bankcard and billing address details hidden

        return self.render_preview(request,
                                   bankcard_form=bankcard_form,
                                  )

    def do_place_order(self, request):
        # Helper method to check that the hidden forms wasn't tinkered
        # with.
        bankcard_form = forms.BankcardForm(request.POST)
        #billing_address_form = forms.BillingAddressForm(request.POST)
        bankcard_form.save()
        """
        if not all([bankcard_form.is_valid(),
                    billing_address_form.is_valid()]):
            messages.error(request, "Invalid submission")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checkout:payment-details'))

        # Attempt to submit the order, passing the bankcard object so that it
        # gets passed back to the 'handle_payment' method below.
        submission = self.build_submission()
        submission['payment_kwargs']['bankcard'] = bankcard_form.bankcard
        submission['payment_kwargs']['billing_address'] = billing_address_form.cleaned_data
        return self.submit(**submission)
        """

    def handle_payment(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):
        """
        Make submission to PayPal
        """
        # Using authorization here (two-stage model).  You could use sale to
        # perform the auth and capture in one step.  The choice is dependent
        # on your business model.
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `clean` method in `oscar.apps.payment.forms.BankcardForm`?

Comment: @H.Yaqub This code ? 

 `    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        number, ccv = data.get('number'), data.get('ccv')
        if number and ccv:
            if bankcards.is_amex(number) and len(ccv) != 4:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(
                    "American Express cards use a 4 digit security code"))
        return data`

Comment: Yes, you can simply make your own form like `MyBankcardForm` inherited from `oscar.BankcardForm` and write your own `clean` method for that form, then use this form in your `views`.